# AppUpdateManager getResult() crashes on some phones

Tags: android, google-play

I have some pretty simple code to check if there is an update:

```
com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfo = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this).getAppUpdateInfo();
appUpdateInfo.addOnCompleteListener(new com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnCompleteListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<AppUpdateInfo> task) {
        AppUpdateInfo result = task.getResult();
    }
}
```

It is on that `task.getResult()` line that a phone is crashing. At first, it was on phones with **Android < 5.0** but now that I've fixed that, I've seen at least one crash on an **Android 9** phone. Of 200 beta users that have run this already, only one phone has crashed.

```
Fatal Exception: com.google.android.play.core.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error: -3
       at com.google.android.play.core.tasks.k.getResult + 18(k.java:18)
       at MyApplication$7.onComplete + 1(MyApplication.java:1103)
       at com.google.android.play.core.tasks.a.run + 23(a.java:23)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 193(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6940(ActivityThread.java:6940)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 537(RuntimeInit.java:537)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Code `-3` means `ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE`, so am I just going to have to try to catch the `RuntimeException`? Seems like an ugly solution when there is already a method for returning error codes.

Comment: you should always have a try/catch exception to avoid fatal errors, but yeah play core library is not properly installed may be on that user's phone

Answer (score 1):

The play core library installation might fail sometime as well. Please check their [release notes](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/release-notes) for an indication.

I think the problem in your case is for an incomplete installation of the Play core library. And yes, if you are still using `com.google.android.play:core:1.5.0`, you might consider switching to version `1.6.0`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.0'
}
```

If there is a problem having the Play Core APIs in your device due to incomplete installation, there is no way that you get an error code for the API which does not exist. Hence, to avoid such `RuntimeException`, I am afraid that you might have to go for a `try/catch` approach.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am using the latest library. Using try catch for now.